# Multithreading in C# increasing CPU usage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cpu-usage

I am using multiple thread for invoking a function as below.
At table level there is queue number. According to the queue

Number the `MAX_Download_Thread` will be set. So that much thread
will be created and work it continuously. When I put
`MAX_Download_Thread` as 4 it consuming 30% of CPU out of 8 processors.
When make it as 10 it almost consuming 70%. Just want to know whether
any better method to reduce this or this is normal.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_Download_THREAD; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        var fileDownloadTread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            new Repo.FILE_DOWNLOAD().PIC_FILE_DOWNLOAD(j);
        });
        fileDownloadTread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you use multiple threads in order to utilize more cpu cores ? (which means it makes sense that the CPU utilization gets higher)

Comment: @wohlstad ya, agree. Just want to know whether im calling it in correct way or not.

Comment: According to your method names, it seems these calls are I/O bound and not CPU bound.  So I'm wonderung how an I/O call can consume so much CPU.

Comment: @Oliver the thread is reading some table and using the value consume a webservice to download an xml file then insert to table again.

Comment: So it seems to be I/O bound (mainly), which means you should probably switch to async / await, which uses also multiple threads, but tries to aggregate multiple tasks into one thread while each one is waiting on I/O. This also means you should use async / await all the way down and use for reading, download and insert also the corresponding async methods.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the `FILE_DOWNLOAD` and `PIC_FILE_DOWNLOAD` methods?

Comment: The line `new Repo.FILE_DOWNLOAD().PIC_FILE_DOWNLOAD(j);` isn't valid C# code. What is the real code here? Can you provide the source?

Answer (score 0):

The point of using multiple Threads is to achieve a higher utilization of multicore CPUs to complete a Task in a shorter amount of time. The higher usage is to be expected, nay desired.

If the work your threads are doing is I/O-Bound (e.g. writing large amounts of Data to a Disk) it might end up taking longer than with fewer threads as data can only be written to a disk in series.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple threads *does* use more CPU. In this case though, that's simply wasted. IO operations like file operations and downloads are carried out by the OS itself, not application code. The application threads just wait for the OS to retrieve data over the network.

To execute multiple downloads concurrently you need asynchronous operations. One way to do this is to use [Parallel.ForeachAsync](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6). The following code will download files in parallel from a list and save them locally:

```
HttpClient _client=new HttpClient();

async Task DownloadUrl(Uri url,DirectoryInfo folder)
{
    var fileName=url.Segments.Last();
    var newPath=Path.Combine(folder.FullName,fileName);

    var stream=await _client.GetStreamAsync(url);
    using var localStream=File.Create(newPath);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(localStream);
}

async Task DonwloadConcurrently(IEnumerable<Uri> urls,DirectoryInfo folder)
{    
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls,async (url,_)=>{
        await DownloadUrl(url,folder);
    });
}
```

This will execute`DownloadUrl` multiple times in parallel. The default number of concurrent tasks is equal to `Environment.ProcessorCount` but can be adjusted

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls, parallelOptions, async (url,_) =>{
    await DownloadUrl(url,folder);
});
```